# Appium - Java - Android: toggleWifi method does not appear in eclipse auto suggestions?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

So I have to turn ON/OFF device Wifi during test.

I am using:

appium - 1.12.1

Java-client - 4.1.2

Android OS version - 8.1.0

Device - Oppo F9 Pro

I have tried:

```
driver[deviceIndex].setConnection(Connection.NONE);
assertEquals(Connection.ALL, driver[deviceIndex].getConnection());
```

But it's not working.

And below one also suggested by Appium to use:

```
driver.toggleWifi();
```

But "toggleWifi" is not suggesting in eclipse.

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 3):

Use the latest stable **java-client**. In order to use toggleWifi() and setNetworkConnection() method you must use AndroidDriver. If you are using AppiumDriver you must typeCast it to android driver like following.

```
((AndroidDriver) driver).toggleWifi();
((AndroidDriver) driver).setNetworkConnection(2);
```

There are certain limitation of using **setNetworkConnection()** method

[image]

> Check [this link](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/network-connection/) for more information about **setNetworkConnection()** method